# Can't bind property. @Input fail bet. parent and child component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, property-binding

I am having difficulties with binding properties from parent to child

this is my **home.ts** (parent)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewComponent } from '../../components/new/new'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  oneObject = {content: "Card content"}
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

and, **home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <new new-name="some name" [new-obj]="oneObject"></new>
  <new new-name="some name 2" ></new>

  <new new-name="some name 4" ></new>

</ion-content>
```

this is my **new.ts** (child component)

- this issue comes from new-obj that is not recognized as a known property on the present component. How is that?

  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

  /**

  - Generated class for the NewComponent component.
    *
  - See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
  - Components.
    */
    @Component({
    selector: 'new',
    templateUrl: 'new.html'
    })
    export class NewComponent {

    **@Input('new-name') name:string;
    @Input('new-obj') myObj:any;**

    text: string;

    constructor() {
    console.log('Hello NewComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
    }

  }

**new.html**

```
 <ion-card>
   <ion-header>

   </ion-header>
   <ion-card-content>
      {{ name }} 
      {{ **myObj?.content }**}
   </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

error message from the console :

[image: error message generated by home.html, although the property 'new-obj' does exist on the **new** component]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your component or your components module into the main application module.

Depending on whether you used the `ionic generate` command to create your component or not, you'll either need to add `ComponentsModule` to the `imports` array in `app.module.ts` (if you use the generator), or add `NewComponent` to the `declarations` array in `app.module.ts` (if you did not use the generator)

In the latter case, your app module file would look like

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { NewComponent } from '../components/new/new';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ IonicApp ],
  declarations: [ MyApp, HomePage, NewComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ HomePage ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp) ],
  providers: [ StatusBar, SplashScreen, IonicErrorHandler ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```